# How do I assign an IP address to a Dell UPS 2700w network interface card?

Tags: dell, ups

We have just installed a NIC into our Dell UPS 2700w and I can't find a way of configuring the card with a static IP address so that we can then access it over our network.

We have installed the monitoring tool on a laptop and managed to connect via USB to monitor the UPS that way but there doesnt appear to be any clear way of setting up the cards address from the GUI.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in your manual page 41

Identification
The identification screens display the following UPS information:
Type and model
Part number
Serial number
UPS firmware
**Network Management Card firmware**
NOTE:
**The NMC firmware screen displays only if the Network Management Card is installed. See “Dell
Network Management Card“ on page 56**

This seems to be from the ups screen not the managing software I would make sure that Network Management Card firmware appears to make sure the UPS is aware of the network card.

The Network Management card manual is separate form the UPS
ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_rack_infrastructure/dell-line-interactive-rack-ups-2700r_User%27s%20Guide14_en-us.pdf

According to this the network card has a serial port somewhere, so you need a laptop with a serial port (obsolete port on laptops nowadays but a usb-to-serial is handy to be around)
you should be connecting to that port and getting access to a console based menu where you configure your card settings.

P.S: You might find PuTTy handy since applications like hyperterminal are also obsolete
http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

Make sure you connect to "Serial" and type in the COM port of your serial card (i.e COM1)

Comment: A belated thank you, your advice worked a treat :)